# On click scroll up or down 100vh pure javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to implement a simple button that on click will scroll the page either up or down 100vh between my sections. I can see plenty of examples doing this with jQuery but I'm looking for a pure javascript solution. I'm not to sure how to achieve it.

Appreciate any advice.

HTML

```
<section class="section section-1">
  <div class="btn"></div>
</section>
<section class="section section-2">
  <div class="btn"></div>
</section>
<section class="section section-3">
  <div class="btn"></div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
.section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh:
}
```

This is what I have come up with so far

```
for (var s = 0; s < btn.length; s++) {
    btn[s].addEventListener('click', function(){
        window.scrollBy(0,1000);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 7):

There are [a few ways to get viewport size in JavaScript](http://ryanve.com/lab/dimensions/).  Using one of these ways, you should be able to scroll as you are with the viewport size in place of your `1000`.

For instance, if I wanted to scroll exactly the height of one viewport with `window.innerHeight`:

```
let pageHeight = window.innerHeight;
window.scrollBy(0, pageHeight);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.btn').forEach(btn => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    let scrollDistance = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    if (btn.className.split(' ').includes('scroll-up')) {
      scrollDistance *= -1;
    }
    window.scrollBy(0, scrollDistance);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.section-1 {
  background-color: blue;
}

.section-2 {
  background-color: red;
}

.section-3 {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<section class="section section-1">
  <div class="btn scroll-down">V</div>
  <div class="btn scroll-up">^</div>
</section>
<section class="section section-2">
  <div class="btn scroll-down">V</div>
  <div class="btn scroll-up">^</div>
</section>
<section class="section section-3">
  <div class="btn scroll-down">V</div>
  <div class="btn scroll-up">^</div>
</section>
```